# SEO-friendly URL design for filtering a resource in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, rest, routes, information-architecture

I need to implement some SEO-friendly sort methods for a resource in Rails 3.  This is what I'm considering doing for collections:

```
/things                  # shows all things
/things/popular          # shows all things ordered by popularity
/things/a-z              # shows all things ordered alphabetically
```

And this for single records:

```
/thing/name-of-a-thing   # shows ONE thing
```

The switching between singular/plural is to avoid *thing-names* colliding with *sort-method-names*.

Until now I have been using `resource :things` which uses `/things` for all actions.  I'm apprehensive to break away from the defaults since I know a lot of thought has gone into making those defaults.  So before I do, I thought I'd seek some advice in case there's a best practice for this kind of thing.

So, is this a good way to solve my problem?  Am I opening myself up to any problems down the road?  Are there better ways to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need define all route by match.

```
match '/things' => 'Things#index'
match '/things/:order' => 'Things#index'
match '/thing/:id' => 'Things#show'
```

and kill your resources, route or use it after all match route define.

Comment: Thanks but that wasn't the question.  I understand how to implement this.  I am asking if it's a good URL design and/or what alternatives/best-practices there are for this problem.